cant find source file
I compiled and executed the main function using a compiler on Windows, and after the return was completed, a gcov_do_dump() function appeared with an error message. The error message was "can't find a source file at"/home/Keith/buildings/mingw/gcc-9.2.0_mingw32 corss native/../../../libgcc/libgcov drive. c ".Because I want to use gcov to get the code coverage information.Acctually,before this error,there is another like "not available _register_frame_info() at ...".
I excluded the problem about mingw.So the most likely problem lies in the configuration of Eclipse.But I cant find any solution .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
